# Similar Invertible Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

If $B$ is similar to $A$, show that there exists an invertible matrix $S$ and another marix $T$ such that $A=ST$ and $B=TS$.

So I know that $B$ being similar to $A$ implies $M^{-1}AM=B$. Can I just say let $A$ be a product of 2 invertible matrices $S$ and $T$ then manipulate $M$ to be either $S$ or $T$?

Comment: You _can_ do this to get an idea of what you must get, but it's not a valid proof. You must show a construction without this supposition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be similar. Then we have $A=S(BS^{-1})=ST$ with $T=BS^{-1}$. It follows that
$$
TS=BS^{-1}S=B.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write the similarity condition as $AM=MB$.

Can you see, that you are quite close to the wanted product presentation?